# Flexbox won't work horizontal (navigation bar)

Tags: css, flexbox, navigationbar

First of all, i'm new to css.

The problem is i'm trying to do a horizontal navigation bar, on the left. But my flexbox doesn't work, the navigation keeps getting vertical. Seems like it's locked, don't know if that's posible.

Please, how can i make my horizontal navigation bar using flexbox?

HTML:

```
   <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HISTORY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
    <h1>ORCA</h1>
   </header>
```

CSS:

```
nav, a {
  font-family: outfit-bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
}
```

When i put "display: flex" i was expecting it to be horizontal, but it was vertical.

I also put display: inline-block and didn't work.

[how it is navigation bar vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYlz1.png)

Comment: You have to put flex inside ul as li tags are children of ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HISTORY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>ORCA</h1>
</header>
```

try to put `display: flex` on the `ul` element. It will put the children in line

If you want to read a really good and detailed resource about flexbox - take a look here -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/